# Boundaries change in double integral

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

Calculate:
$$\int_0^1  \int_0^{x^3} e^\frac{y}{x} dydx$$
Obviously i need to change it to $dxdy$ thus i need to change the boundaries of the second integral but how to do that in this case?

Comment: I think you'll find this problem more difficult if you switch the order of integration

Comment: Boundaries are fine.

Comment: Thus should i use polar coordinates in this integral or just leave it as it is?

Comment: As is. It's fairly straightforward, although it looks complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As presented the integral may be best suited. By integrating $y$ first makes $x$ a "constant" in that particular integral. Alternatively if $x$ is is integrated first a change of variable will need to be made, ie $x \to \frac{1}{t}$ as well as changing the integration limits.

\begin{align}
\int_0^1  \,  \int_0^{x^3} e^{\frac{y}{x}} \, dy \, dx &= \int_{0}^{1} \left[ x \, e^{\frac{y}{x}} \right]_{0}^{x^{3}} \, dx \\
&= \int_{0}^{1} x \, (e^{x^{2}} -1) \, dx \\
&= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{d}{dx} \left[ \frac{1}{2} \, e^{x^{2}} - \frac{x^{2}}{2} \right] \, dx \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \, \left[ e^{x^{2}} - x^{2} \right]_{0}^{1} \\
&= \frac{e - 2}{2}.
\end{align}